# Converting time, so can create link to add to calendar

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I would like to know How can I convert a given time into a proper time, so we can create a link which will generate event with just one click!

**Example**

We want to add a calendar event ([sample like can be found here](https://parcel.io/tools/calendar))

**Title**: Interview with Mark Zuckerberg
**Location**: google meet link
**Start**: 06/08/2022 @ 04:00 PM
**End**: 06/08/2022 @ 04:45 PM
**Description**: Meeting Details here

Now when we put the above details in the tool mentioned above, it generates a link, there we can simply replace the get variables and it becomes dynamic(just like we do using programming)

[Add to calendar link generated by the tool](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&dates=20220806T103000Z%2F20220806T111500Z&details=Meeting%20Details%20here&location=google%20meet%20link&text=Interview%20with%20Mark%20Zuckerberg)

**Problem**

Not able to convert this
*06/08/2022 04:00 PM to 06/08/2022 04:45 PM* into *20220806T103000Z/20220806T111500Z*

**Pointers**

1. Have to add time in that format only(04:45 PM) because non tech people will also use it
2. Can we generate automatic end time(based on some calculation, like each meeting will last 45 minutes, so we can avoid that calculation
3. We Use this feature in bulk, that is why add to calendar link generation is important for us

Answer (score 1):

### Option 01 - One formula one cell one click!

> **Use this formula**

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(F2:F="",,HYPERLINK("https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/eventedit?dates="&IF(F2:F="",,SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(D2:D, "dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS"),"/",""),":",""), " ","T")&"Z"&"/"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(E2:E, "dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS"),"/",""),":",""), " ","T")&"Z")&"&details="&ENCODEURL( C2:C)&"&location="&ENCODEURL( B2:B)&"&text="&ENCODEURL( A2:A),"Calendar Link")))
```

[image: Convert date time, create link to a calendar]

**Let's check links**

[image: Convert date time, create link to a calendar]

---

[image: Convert date time, create link to a calendar]

### Option 02 - Multiple Steps

**Use this formula to get the time formatted**

> With this formula you need to input Start time and duration only.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(F2:F="",,SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(D2:D, "dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS"),"/",""),":",""), " ","T")&"Z"&"/"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(E2:E, "dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS"),"/",""),":",""), " ","T")&"Z"))
```

[image]

**To Get the Link for calendars use this formula**

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(F2:F="",,"https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/eventedit?dates="&G2:G&"&details="&ENCODEURL( C2:C)&"&location="&ENCODEURL( B2:B)&"&text="&ENCODEURL( A2:A)))
```

[image]